# Recuperar o valor de um atributo de um objeto genérico em Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, xml, nosql

Eu estou fazendo um sistema em que leio objetos Java, de tipos diferentes, de arquivos XML. Logo não tenho um único tipo de objeto e consequentemente não conheço seus atributos ou métodos. Eu gostaria de realizar uma pesquisa, em que entrasse com uma string indicando atributo e valor, e essa pesquisa me retornasse todos os objetos que tivessem esse atributos e que fosse igual ao valor em um `ArrayList`.

Exemplo:
Tenho alguns arquivos XML, dos tipos `Produto`, `Pessoa` e `Carro`, já estão lidos e instanciados. Quero procurar os objetos que tenham a seguinte característica `ano: 1996`, as classes `Produto` e `Carro` tem o atributo `ano`, porém `Pessoa` não tem ele. Percorreria os objetos, onde tivesse seria analisado se o valor é igual e tomaria os passos necessários, caso o atributo não existisse retornaria `null` ou uma `Exception` a ser tratada.

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer essa recuperação, o maior problema é quem podem ser objetos de tipos diferentes, é que um trabalho de banco não-relacional, se fosse relacional seria muito fácil, com os tipos definidos.

Gostaria de algo que como um `.getAtributte (String nomeAtributo, Object o)`, em que o primeiro é um nome do atributo e o segundo o objeto analisado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de uma entidade única, por exemplo `Entidade`, vc precisará ter dentro dela um `Map<String, Object> mapa`.

A cada valor obtido do xml, vc atribuirá no objeto utilizado `mapa.put(colunaXml, valorColunaXml)`.

Seu método `getAttribute(String coluna)` deverá seguir o padrão

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapa.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getKey().equals(coluna.toString()){
        return entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa ideia, vou testar :) !

Comment: Sua resposta junto com essa solucionaram meus problemas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe de ObjetoXML que será comum a todos eles.

Dentro de ObjetoXML, você pode colocar uma estrutura dinâmica como uma Lista Encadeada e ao criar o objeto, você popula a lista com os objetos que você recebeu do banco de dados.

Em ObjetoXML, você cria então o método:
o.getAtributte (String nomeAtributo)

Que basicamente vai percorrer a lista de atributos e responder o valor se existir, ou nulo, se o atributo não existir na lista.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas creio que você não entendeu, os tipos dos objetos podem ser quaisquer, vou usar o sistema que eu estou fazendo como um mini-banco de dados para uma aplicação maior, ela que fornecerá as classes, porém não é possível determinar quais gets eu vou usar, em Java não tem como no PHP, como objeto.atributo()

Comment: Editei a resposta para o que me pareceu ser a pergunta, relendo ela. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: Lista encadeada, ou um mapa? Por mim um mapa cairia melhor na situação.

Comment: E também se for criado um ObjetoXML para cada entidade de xml, não há necessidade do segundo parametro no método.

Comment: Depende da possibilidade de o XML ter atributos repetidos, mas tem razão, provavelmente um mapa atenderia.

Comment: Mas eu não conhecerei as entidades antecipadamente, justamente eu estou com problemas na criação desse getAtributte(), na codificação seja ele com uma lista ou mapa essa parte é indiferente, a questão problemática é verificar a existência do atributo, identificar o tipo do atributo e consequentemente recuperar esse valor

Comment: Se voce já tem a parte que fará a leitura do arquivo xml, a cada item lido, insira no mapa da entidade com a chave sendo a "coluna" do xml, e seu respectivo valor.

Comment: hum... você não conhece nada do banco de dados? é possível mexer nele para ter um cabeçalho ou algo que você conheça sempre?
Tipo, você não sabe onde começa um atributo e onde está o valor?

Comment: Trabalhando com uma estrutura fixa de um banco de dados relacional é simples sabemos onde tudo está, o problema é quando se trabalha com um banco de dados não-relacional, em que dados de uma mesma coleção tem atributos diferentes, como por exemplo em um banco orientados a documentos.